# Spivak Calculus Chapter 1 Question 24(a)

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let us agree, for definiteness, that $a_1 + ... + a_n = a_1 + (a_2 + (a_3 + ... + (a_{n-2} + (a_{n-1} + a_n))...)$.

1.24 Prove that 
\begin{equation*}
    (a_1 + ... + a_k) + a_{k+1} = a_1 + ... + a_{k+1}
\end{equation*}

Here's what I have so far:

I need to see if this is true for a base case.  For $n=3$, I have
\begin{equation*}
    (a_1 + a_2) + a_3 = a_1 + (a_2 + a_3) \tag*{(associativity)}.
\end{equation*}
I assume that 
\begin{equation*}
        (a_1 + ... + a_{l-1}) + a_l = a_1 + ... + a_l.
\end{equation*}
I wish to prove
\begin{equation*}
            (a_1 + ... + a_{l}) + a_{l+1} = a_1 + ... + a_{l+1}.
\end{equation*}

I'll begin with 
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
           (a_1 + ... + a_{l}) + a_{l+1} &=    (a_1 + ... + a_{l-1}+ a_{l}) + a_{l+1} \\
           &=    ((a_1 + ... + a_{l-1})+ a_{l}) + a_{l+1}. \\
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
Let $b_{n-1} = (a_1 + ... + a_{n-1})$.  Continuing the equation
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        &= (b_{n-1} + a_l) + a_{l+1} \\
                &= b_{n-1} + (a_l + a_{l+1}) \\
                &= (a_1 + ... + a_{l-1}) + (a_{l}) + a_{l+1})
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
and now I'm stuck.

Comment: You need to edit your first line, with the horrendous parentheses mess, FYI.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out.  You use strong induction and then the hypothesis holds for all 3 <= n <= k.